# Open MultiUpload modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, modal-dialog

Could you please tell me how to open a MultiUpload modal form, without using or displaying the single upload form?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetList",
            listName: "Briefkasten",
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                id = $(xData.responseXML).find("List").attr("ID");
            }
        });

        reference = "./_layouts/Upload.aspx?List=" + id + "&amp;RootFolder=";

        $('#UploadButton').click(function (event) {
            if ($.browser.msie) {
                NewItem2(event, reference);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have written this code for single upload. But I stuck on multi. I also tried to set the anchor for multi upload at the end of the reference, but no way, the NewItem2() isn´t working properly this way. Are there any suggs?

Thanks for all effort!

Comment: I solved the problem on my onw ;-)

Comment: The NewItem2() is more or less the "SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog()" (or is based on it) so it´s easy after you´ve got this point ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the `MultipleUpload=1` query string to the URL and it will be the multiple upload version.